# Repeating notification every 1 hour

Tags: android

I have asked a question before 2 days about daily notification and i put my code and i didn't get any useful answer so i need someone write a code that show notification every 1 hour .
caution  (i have write a code doing that but i was have a problem that is every time i open the activity it gives me a notification i don't need that i just want it give a notification at the first time i run app or press a button to start it then the service runs to give notification every 1 hour ) . 
Hope anyone can help me .
Thanks.

Comment: Well, that's a good way to annoy your user.

Comment: it's not for annoying users but it's the main idea of the app to remember the user for somthing

Comment: so I didn't get any answer for my first question guys

Comment: I hope i got answer for the topic update .

Comment: You can try this answer It worked for me [How to show local notification every hour using service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44862193/4389867)

Answer (score 1):

Well this seems like a two part question, for one the effect that you want to wait and be able to check to start the notifications and to save that value.  SharedPrefence's can do this, you could save a boolean value to see whether or not a alarm should be set.  Easy enough to access.

```
public boolean saveSharedBoolValue(String key, Boolean value, Context localContext) {
        SharedPreferences sp = localContext.getSharedPreferences("FILE_NAME", 0);
        Editor edit = sp.edit();
        edit.putBoolean(key, value);
        return edit.commit();
    }
public Boolean getSharedBoolValue(String key, Context localContext)
    {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = localContext.getSharedPreferences("FILE_NAME", 0);
        Boolean value = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, false);
        return value;
    }
```

Something like this.  With alarm notifications, that start on startup I had this similar issue.  What I noticed was that I was creating an alert for earlier than my present time and it created a single notification automatically.

That may not be your issue though,

```
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis() +5*1000);
```

this line from your code.  Isn't it essentially creating an alarm just right after it starts?  5000 milli seconds aren't much after present time.

Comment: i didn't use sharedprefernce  before can u give me some explain for it plz , and my issue is that it starts normaly and make a notification every 1h normaly but if i start activity between an hour and the next hour it gives me a notification a resets the time of alarm how can i avoid that ??

Comment: Sure, sharedpreference is essentially an easy way to store certain values on the device.  I didn't add the save code earlier so let me add it right now,  the key that is needed though is whatever you choose for its variable essentially.

Comment: and where can i call getsharedboolean method to save the value to the activity ???

Comment: The effect of resetting your alarm is due to  your pending intents they all have the same id of 0, so when you alarm manager has one setup already it gets replaced by the other alarm.  I've ran it before where I had an array of alarm ids and could select which alarms to turn of it wanted.

Comment: well to save it you wont call getsharedboolean, youd call save, and proably on radiobutton click if it starts then.