# How to show local notification every hour using service

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, android-notifications, show

I want to show local notification on every hour or particular seconds using service, I have tried to implement this functionality, but I didn't got success.

My code is look like below

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION");
        notificationIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");

        PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 100, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Log.d("day for notification:::", String.valueOf(notification_day));

            cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, notification_day);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 4 * 60 * 60, broadcast);
```

Comment: Are you used Alarm Manager and job Scheduler.Post your code what you tried.

Comment: Yes! I have used.

Comment: Have updated code!

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems to be OK.
The only thing that can be problematic is the interval 4*60*60 is too short which is 14.4 seconds.

Moreover it seems like you're not directing the intent to a specific receiver. you should do like this:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(this.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 60, pendingIntent);
```

And you should catch it in:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, EVentsPerform.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.applogo)
            .setContentTitle("text")
            .setContentText("text")
            .setWhen(when)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    notificationManager.notify(yourId, mNotifyBuilder.build());

}

}
```

Add this to your manifest file:

```
 <!-- permission required to use Alarm Manager -->
 <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>

 <!-- Register the Alarm Receiver -->
 <receiver android:name="com.example.alarmmanagernotifcation.AlarmReceiver"/>
```

Comment: But I want to show notification when application is closed, so have to implement in *Service*, Have you an idea about it?

Comment: The receiver will do it for you. if the service purpose is just show the notification you don't need it.
The receiver can do it for you instead.

Comment: Did you registered the receiver in manifest and used it in the code ?

Comment: Yeah i have registered!

Comment: That's weird. take a look in this tutorial:
http://karanbalkar.com/2013/07/tutorial-41-using-alarmmanager-and-broadcastreceiver-in-android/